# How to decrypt database passwords connections in Pentaho?

Tags: cryptography, pentaho

I forgot a password used in a pentaho transformation. When I open the kdb or ktr file all I see is a encrypted value like `Encrypted xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz`

I want to find out the original value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The code below can decrypt any encrypted string. You can use a `Modified JavaScript Value`

```js
var password = org.pentaho.di.core.encryption.Encr.decryptPassword(encryptedValue);
```